# How to to execute a Makefile from a server

Tags: ant, makefile, terminal

Hi I'm completly knew to Ant files and makefiles. I have a file structure that was setup by someone else. They basically have an ant file that is executed from a Makefile. The ant file builds all the js scripts into one file and all other files related to the project.

I have a few questions I want to ask here before I run the script.

1. Can I execute a Makefile from a server. I have SSH access to the
   server and its folders via terminal. Can I add a command to terminal
   that will execute the Makefile on the server.
2. The makefile has 3 setup modes, the ones I'm interested in are the
   first 2. Mostly the debug build.

> release :     $(ANT_EXE) -f $(ANT_FILE) "build release"
>
> debug :   $(ANT_EXE) -f $(ANT_FILE) "build debug"

The file name is just Makefile

1. How would I execute the file using just the debug

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just access your machine using SSH and execute your Makefile as if you were physically using the machine. ie:

```
Chapsterj@home $> ssh ssh.machine.net
  Welcome to machine.net
Chapsterj@machine.net $> make debug
  Blablabla I am a Makefile
  I am making your binary.
  (Compilation nightmare)
```

Reminder on Makefile rules:

- A "make" with no arguments will execute the first rule.
- Use "make rule" to execute a certain rule (in you case "make debug" to run the "debug" rule

Comment: Thanks Josh what do you mean by machine. I actually have a url for the SSH and a password which lets me into the root folder via terminal. example: ssh chapsterj@chapsterj-bla.com. Once in there is there any folder I need to cd into to run the "make debug" comman. Or will it find the file called Makefile which is in quite a few sub folders.

Comment: By "machine" I mean "remote server". And yes you have to cd up to the folder where the Makefile is located. The 'make' utility (by default) always looks for the makefile in the current folder. Though you can use 'make --file=/path/to/file' or 'make -f /this/leads/to/a/Makefile'.

More informations: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Names

Answer (score 1):

Since you have SSH access to the server, and you know where the makefile and ant script file are, I recommend to use the ant task  to execute your remote ant files.

For example, put the following target into your local ant build script file (build.xml in this example)

```
<target name="run-remote-ant-script">
    <sshexec host="chapsterj-bla.com" 
         username="chapsterj" password="your password here"
         trust="true"
         command="ant -f [path-to-your-ant-script-file/your-ant-file-name] build debug"
         failonerror="false"/>
</target>
```

cd to the directory that contains your local build.xml in your local machine, and run

> ant run-remote-ant-script

ant will do other job for you.

Comment: Never used ant before but...wow, this sshexec function sure could come in handy O_O I upvote for ant's greatness :)

Comment: In the big ant build file of my job, there are almost one hundred lines of sshexec lol...